# rxjs groupBy and compare each emitted object with latest of other groups

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Is it possible with rxjs to groupBy a object property and when compare new emitted event of one group with the latest value of each other group? After this merge all streams together to one again.

Eg I have 5 rooms each with a light. An emitter randomly turns a light on or off in one of the rooms. I like to know in the pipe when the lights are off or on in all rooms and when add a property allLightsOff to the emitted object.

```
const source = interval(1000).pipe(
  map((e) => {
    return {
      iteration: e,
      room: Math.floor(Math.random()*5),
      lightOn: Math.round(Math.random()),
      allLightsOff: null
    };
  }),
  groupBy((o) => o.room)
  // how to compare one room with all others?
  // how to merge alls groups to a single stream together again?
);
const subscribe = source.subscribe((o) => console.log(o));
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of state context for these rooms with current state data for each room to access it at any time?

Comment: @Zac, what do you mean by state context? I have a stream like the one simulated above.

Comment: What I mean is, where do you store or keep this emitted data?

Comment: @Zac, depends, sometimes it's coming in as a stream, sometimes as array from a timeseries db.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it like the following using `ReplaySubject(1)` and `switchMap` + `combileLatest`:

```
const source = interval(1000).pipe(
  map((e) => {
    return {
      iteration: e,
      room: Math.floor(Math.random()*5),
      lightOn: Math.round(Math.random()),
      allLightsOff: null
    };
  }),
  groupBy((o) => o.room, undefined, undefined, () => new ReplaySubject(1)),
  scan((allGroups, group) => [...allGroups, group], []),
  switchMap(groups => combineLatest(groups)),
  map((rooms: any[]) => {
    if (rooms.every(room => room.lightOn)) {
      console.log(rooms);
      return 'all on';
    } else if (rooms.every(room => !room.lightOn)) {
      console.log(rooms);
      return 'all off';
    }
    return 'some on, some off';
  }),
);

const subscribe = source.subscribe((o) => console.log(o));
```

Each new group is `ReplaySubject(1)` that replays its last value so when a new group is added it'll be accumulated by `scan` and then `combileLatest` will subscribe to the new list.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-u9w73k?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Thx Martin, great idea. Leaves one question open to me, how do I know which room was the latest, so I can emit this one with updated property allLightsOff:1?

Comment: I think each room has `iteration` property with index generated by `interval`so the room with the highest `iteration` was the last one that has changed.

Comment: Iteration is just in my sample an increasing  number. In reality I do not have it available as it is a random uuid.

Comment: @Manuel You can use `map((room, index) => ({ ...room, index }))` and add index automatically generated by `map()`.